# kickstart autopart with xfs ftype=1

Tags: linux, anaconda, centos7, redhat

I'm using anaconda kickstart to setup a centos box, with the convenient `autopart` command.  By default it creates xfs lvm volumes, which is great.  However, xfs is created with the default `ftype` of `0`, which makes the volumes unsuitable for Docker's OverlayFS (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#prerequisites)).

If I were making these volumes by hand, I would do

```
mkfs -t xfs -n ftype=1 ...
```

But I can't see how to get the `ftype` parameter into `autopart`.  Is there a way to get extra parameters into autopart's volume formatting?

Edit: This is with Centos 7.2.1511

Comment: This question is off topic on Stack Overflow, so it's going to get closed. You might want to move it over to https://unix.stackexchage.com. You'll want to include some additional details...like, what version of CentOS are you installing? From what media? I just performed a fresh CentOS 7 install and the root filesystem was created with `ftype=1`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize it was version-dependent. I've added the (admittedly old) centos version.

Comment: I know at some point during the centos 7 timeline the default was changed to be `ftype=1`. Is there any reason you can't just update to a later CentOS 7 minor release?

Comment: It looks like Centos 7.3.1611 and later default to `ftype=1`.

Comment: Sadly, I can't update. :(